# UITableViewController return to next text field in Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController and a class which implements UITableView.

```
@interface CreateEditViewController : UITableViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

I also have a class which implements UITableViewCell and each Cell contains a textfield.

```
@interface CreateEditCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *celltextfield;


@end
```

In my TableView controller class I implemented the three methods `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `numberOfRowsInSection` and `textFieldShouldReturn`

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I assign each cell's textfield delegate to self and give each one a tag in a switch case.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CreateEditCell* cell = nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.celltextfield.delegate = self;
    cell.celltextfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;

    switch (indexPath.row) {

        case 0:

            cell.celltextfield.tag = 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.celltextfield.tag = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.celltextfield.tag = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.celltextfield.tag = 3;
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 4;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSInteger nexttag = textField.tag+1;
    UIResponder* nextresponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nexttag];
    if(nextresponder){
        [nextresponder becomeFirstResponder];
    }else{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        NSLog(@"Nothing to return to");
    }


    return NO;
}
```

So the return to next text field worked in my previous design where I didn't have text fields being generated dynamically by cells. Rather I had individual textfields on the story board and assigned their tags in viewdidload. But right now with the current design, when I hit the return button rather than going to the next cell it just prints "Nothing to return to" which doesn't make sense since I have four cells (four text fields) each with their own unique tag. So my question is, how do return to the next text field with the current design I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem lies in the line:

```
UIResponder* nextresponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nexttag];
```

`textField.superview` refers to the `contentView` of the cell containing `textField`. The other textfields are not descendants of the `contentView` (nor of the cell itself), so calling `viewWithTag:` on it will always return nil for the tags of the other textfields.

You need to go up higher in the view hierarchy when calling `viewWithTag:` in order to find the other textfields. Either `self.view` or `self.tableView` (which both refer to the same view since this view controller is a subclass of `UITableViewController`) should work:

```
UIResponder* nextresponder = [self.tableView viewWithTag:nexttag];
```

---

Also (unrelated to your actual question), you can simplify the following:

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell.celltextfield.tag = 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.celltextfield.tag = 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.celltextfield.tag = 2;
        break;
    case 3:
        cell.celltextfield.tag = 3;
        break;
}
```

to just one line:

```
cell.celltextfield.tag = indexPath.row;
```

And another unrelated point: I recommend adding some offset to your textfield tags instead of starting from zero, as zero is the default tag for *all* views, so you won't be able to differentiate the first textfield (since it has a tag of 0) from views like your `tableView`, the `tableView`'s cells, the cells' `contentView`s, etc. when using `viewWithTag:`. Something like:

```
cell.celltextfield.tag = indexPath.row + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for actually mentioning I could just simplify the tags by assigning them to the rows! So I take it self.tableView is already existent since it implements UITableView? Edit: All of those suggestions worked thank you!

Comment: Yep, `tableView` is a property on `UITableViewController`, so your subclass has access to it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your design change also caused a view hierarchy change of you text fields. They are not directly siblings any more, but hosted in cells which are hosted in the table view.
Therefore, when you focus a new text field, you must find the cell that hosts the text field, and even more, this cell might not be visible, so you need to scroll to it first.

Hence:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSInteger nexttag = textField.tag+1;
    if (nexttag < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]) {
        NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:nexttag inSection:0];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
        CreateEditCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath];
        if (cell == nil) {
            // cell is not displayed at the moment, therefore we 
            // "force-scroll" (without animation) to it
            // and then retrieve it again:
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
            cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath];
        }
        [cell.celltextfield becomeFirstResponder];
    }else{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        NSLog(@"Nothing to return to");
    }

    return NO;
}
```

This code is a little *quick & dirty* because if the cell is not visible, you cannot retrieve it by calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Even an animated `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` does not help, because you need to wait for the cell to be displayed. So my work-around just scrolls again, without animation.

A far better solution would be to implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` and in `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` you can then focus the text field -- but be aware that you should only do so if the scrolling was caused by `textFieldShouldReturn` and not by the users scrolling activity. So you would use a flag (or better: a custom delegate / closure) which you could check to identify what kind of scroll animation did end.

Comment: Yes so my main issue was, when I wanted to type in UITextField, sometimes the keyboard would cover the textfield. And I read that using a UITableView with the textfield inside the cells would cause the table to scroll up when I change to diffferent text fields. I'll try the above solution and if I can't get that to work I'll try yours. Edit: Your solution does work for people reading in the future. I went with the above solution because it was simpler and one line change of code! Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, I thought each cell has it's own text field, and `textFieldShouldReturn` should focus the next text field (in the next cell) -- which might not be visible, and hence no `viewForTag` exists. But maybe I thought too far :-)

Comment: In my current design the cell could never be null because the only way textFieldShouldReturn could be triggered was if the user explciitly pressed the cell and specifically the text field inside it. Which in that case, cellForRowAtIndexPath would have already allocated the cell.

Comment: No, you are correct @AndreasOetjen – that's something I missed from my answer. It's definitely possible that the next cell is not visible, so some kind of scrolling would be necessary before calling `viewWithTag:`.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen You're absoltuely right in that some cells would not be visible unless you scrolled. I think I probably don't have to worry about that because with the number of cells I'm creating it probably will always be visible. But definitely something to keep in mind.